# HashMap transformation using streams

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream

I have `Map<Long, Map<String, String>> map`, and I have to filter that by key and further get only value.
I'm trying to do some like that:

```java
Map<Object, Object> resultMap = map.entrySet().stream()
  .filter(x -> x.getKey().equals(filterValue))
  .map(Map.Entry::getValue).collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k,v -> v));
```

But I got `Map<Object, Object>` map instead of `Map<String, String>`.

Maybe, there is some better way to do it.

Comment: `Map<String, String> result = foo.entrySet().stream().filter(x -> x.getKey().equals(filterValue)).map(Entry::getValue).map(Map::entrySet).flatMap(Set::stream).collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));` [Ideone demo](https://ideone.com/yN2Vgg) (please ignore runtime exception - Ideone should demonstrate tath the compilation passes)

Comment: Thank you! That works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work as you need:

```java
Map<String, String> resultMap = map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(x -> x.getKey().equals(filterValue))
    .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().entrySet().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set values of map to specific types in collector

```
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Object::toString, Object::toString))
```

Answer (score 0):

From `map.entrySet().stream().filter(x -> x.getKey().equals(filterValue))`, it could be understood that `filterValue` is a `long`. There is no need to stream a map to filter out the values matching a particular key. Because map keys are unique, and there will be only one matching key. You could have just used:

```java
Map<String, String> result = map.get(filterValue);
```